# How will Apple's switch to ARM (Apple Silicon) affect compatibility with Linux / Unix tools and APIs?

Tags: homebrew, macports, apple-silicon

At the moment, a huge argument for using Macs in academic and research settings (and possibly quite a few other use cases) is the compatibility with the Linux/Unix ecosystem, through Homebrew, Macports and similar projects, and of course the classical terminal (nowadays using zsh) that allows control over system internals. Users in many areas would not be able to work with a "plain" macOS without access to specialized applications which are generally only available on Linux.

Is there already information available as to what [Apple's move to the ARM CPU architecture ("Apple Silicon")](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2020/06/apple-announces-mac-transition-to-apple-silicon/) is going to mean for this compatibility? Will it still be possible to compile programs from source on macOS? How about graphical Linux tools, will there still be a possibility to use X / Wayland / whatever on the Mac?

I do understand that it is possible for Apple to arbitrarily restrict the OS in order to make it as hard as possible for users to do that. My question is aimed more at the practical / technical side of things: Is it enough to say "compiling for ARM is easy enough, no worries" or are there hidden issues?

Comment: Apple has made big changes before, I’m sure it can again. I enjoyed the macs that used the 68000 processor and am happy with the ones (5 at the last count, including mini, imac & 2 macbook pros) that I have now.

Comment: Someone needs to get XQUARTZ recompiled

Comment: I love that you address the problem with asking non-practical questions. I don’t see this as a good candidate for answers other than some hot takes from everyone, though. Especially since you asked about 4 questions by my count in the body. Rather than closing this. I’ll try to give hot take answers saying, lots of fud - no reason for concern, this is my hot take... I expect this to be closed on quality reasons, though and wouldn’t reverse that decision unless the scope gets seriously narrowed. (ED - looks like it’s closed before I could expound on FUD surrounding this)

Comment: @bmike Sigh. OK, I'll rephrase it later so that the part that is answerable with hard facts ("Is there already information available...", which can be answered by a simple link, if anything exists) stands out and so that it is understandable that it is intended as a *modifier* to the following opinion-inviting questions. As a non-native speaker, it is sometimes challenging to walk the line between linguistic precision and intuitive readability that is required on SE.

Comment: Don’t stress too much. I like to let edits sit a bit. I think there’s room for most if not all your questions and if we can avoid writing each in sequence, that might be better.

Comment: My hot take...just like everything else, whether it’s x86 (32bit) or AMD64 (Intel/AMD 64bit) or IA-64 (Itanium 64bit) or  PPC, **it will have to be recompiled.**   So, history is your guide here.  As for tools - they’re not “generally available on Linux” in the sense you’re referring to.  The source is available and can be compiled on various platforms - macOS, FreeBSD, Linux etc.  I’ve had a modern OS (FreeBSD 11) running on a XServe G4 including XOrg - it had to be recompiled, but it was done; and it worked.

Comment: They literally stated in platform state of the union, "they will be amazing UNIX machines": https://scriptingosx.com/2020/06/macos-11/

Answer (score 3):

The betas of Big Sur (on Intel, at least) have the all the same Unix underpinnings and other components as before. (Even python 2.7, which was widely expected to be removed!)

You would hear a lot of noise it if Apple ditched its 'certified Unix™' status.

Xcode isn't going anywhere either, so you can compile any Unix code you've got source for.

As for X11, that hasn't been updated for years, so will have to run in emulation until someone recompiles it (hopefully fixing the Retina display issues while they're at it).

There may be teething problems, particularly in the early days. But I'd say that recompiled code is likely to have fewer problems than Rosetta emulated stuff.

Comment: If X11 is in Emulation then all X programs will have to run under the emulator

Comment: @mmmmmm Yes. It might spur someone to revive the project.

Comment: Huh?  Maybe it’s your wording, but this whole answer makes no sense. *still on Intel, admittedly...*.  Is being on Intel a bad thing?   Including Python (any version) is not an “underpinning” of Unix. Xcode “still a thing”. Why wouldn’t it be thing?  It’s a very current and widely used product.  While X hasn’t been updated since 2012, that doesn’t stop it from individual modules bring updated as needed, which it has and X has been installed on R-Pi, which is ARM, so....emulation?

Comment: @Allan - By "still on Intel, admittedly", I mean I haven't seen a beta of Big Sur running on ARM, so I don't know if it's any different. Yes, OK, python isn't part of Unix, but it's an example showing that MacOS still contains all the things it always has. I'm confirming to the OP that Xcode still exists (yes, why wouldn't it?) so that compiling for new architectures can be done. X11 would need to run in emulation unless someone does recompile it, surely? I'm not saying it can't be done.

Comment: Thats what I don’t get.  When ARM Macs are released, Big Sur would be replaced by something else, so why speculate on that?  That said, have you seen OSes on different architectures (i.e Solaris on SPARC vs Intel or WinNT on RISC vs Intel). How *different* do you think they are?  I’m not understanding the “confirming” of XCode being current - was there a concern that it wasn’t?  macOS doesn’t *always* have the things it once did - it’s actually removing Python and other scripting languages  in upcoming releases.  See: https://apple.co/31EexYe

Comment: No, there are Big Sur builds on ARM, running on the Developer boxes. The OP was concerned that he wouldn't be able to compile Unix source. I was reassuring him that Xcode will still be there. I know that Apple said they were removing python, which is why it's inclusion is noteworthy.

Comment: What I’m trying to say is what you wrote in that comment doesn’t come across in the answer... as I said...”Maybe it’s wording...”

Comment: @Allan what do you speculate they will do for ASi Macs? File --> New Project --> MyCoolNewOperatingSystemForMacsWithAppleSilicon ?